# Posix Regex error in C

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm having trouble with my posix regex in C. I just want to check that a string is alphanumeric (pretty straightforward) but I'm having trouble whenever I try to add anchors. 
The regex is `char pattern[20] = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";` but when I try to match it against
`char* str = "9abc1";` my program informs me it's not a match. I've also tried `^[[:alnum:]]+$` with similar issues. I keep tinkering with the syntax of my regex, but when I can get it to match, then adding hyphens also gives me incorrect results (matches where there shouldn't be, particularly if the hyphen is at the end). 
Clearly I'm making some basic syntax error, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps you should paste a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting `REG_EXTENDED`? This works fine for me:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void) {
    regex_t rtype;

    int i = regcomp(&rtype, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED);
    if ( i == 0 ) {
        printf("Regex compiled successfully.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Regex did not successfully compile.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    i = regexec(&rtype, "9abc1", 0, NULL, 0);
    if ( i == 0 ) {
        printf("Matched regex.\n");
    } else {
        char buffer[1000];
        regerror(i, &rtype, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Regex error: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and yields:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch/$ ./regextest
Regex compiled successfully.
Matched regex.
```

The `+` quantifier isn't present in POSIX basic regex syntax, this may be what's throwing you off.